# A function that works in Vb.net a class, but not in a module

Tags: vb.net, module, delegates

Writing in VS2012 using VB.Net, I am using a table of functions to interpret a script file. 
The script file consists of lines like this:

```
#keyword,(string)
```

All the functions, and the dictionary, live in a module. All the functions have the same signature, so I can use them as delegates.

In a form, I read the script file and then process each line, extracting the keyword and the string accompanying it. Using the keyword, I get the address of the function I want from the dictionary, then call this function, passing it the string as a parameter. I use this syntax:

```
fndic(keyword)(string)
```

This works fine, finding the right function and executing it properly, except...

One of the functions puts text on a label:

```
Public Function fhdr(s As String) As Boolean
        Form1.Header.Text = s
    End Function
```

Only it doesn't. So to see if it works, I put in an extra line:

```
Public Function fhdr(s As String) As Boolean
        MessageBox.Show("hdr " + Form1.Header.Text + " new " + s)
        Form1.Header.Text = s
    End Function
```

The message box appears, but the text still doesn't. So I put this function in the class of the form, and now it works!

So my question is – why does the function alter the form when it's in the form's code, but not when it's in the module?

Is there some arcane statement I must put in the module to make it aware of the form? Or should I just dump all the code into the form, making a big unlovely stew with 40 functions in it?

Comment: Is the method possibly being executed on a secondary thread, i.e. not the UI thread?

Comment: @jmcilhinney if there is some other thread being spawned, VB is doing it without my sayso and without telling me either.

Comment: Is `Form1` the startup form or did you display it yourself? If the latter, can you post the code you used to display it?

Comment: Form1 is the startup form.

Comment: You're referring to the default instance in the module and the most likely reason that it's not working is that it's a different instance than the one you're looking at. The only two reasons I can think of that that would be the case though, are that the code is executed on a secondary thread (default instances are thread-specific) or it's not the default instance that you're looking at.  You're telling me that neither of those are the case though, so I'm stumped. Maybe it is a second thread and you just don't realise. How does this code get kicked off?

Comment: `just dump all the code into the form, making a big unlovely stew` You could create a class and move them there to make a neat, Object Oriented, task-specific processor

Comment: Actually that's what I ended up doing, but the question of the odd behavior of the function when it's in the module remains.